# AS3 - Local P2P networking receiving only "undefined" data

Tags: actionscript-3, networking, p2p

I'm trying to make a simple P2P networking system to send messages to other Flash Players on your network.

However, when I send a message the receiving player doesn't receive a message but rather a undefined object.

I did allow Flash Player in my Virus Scanner (NOD 32) and my Windows Firewall by the way.

Here's my P2P class:

```
package com.snakybo.as3framework.network {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.net.GroupSpecifier;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetGroup;

    /** @author Kevin */
    public class P2P extends NetConnection {
        private var netCon:NetConnection;
        private var netGroup:NetGroup;

        private var handler:Function;
        private var groupName:String;

        public function P2P(groupName:String, handler:Function) {
            this.groupName = groupName;
            this.handler = handler;

            netCon = new NetConnection();
            netCon.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, conHandler);
            netCon.connect("rtmfp:");
        }

        /** Post a message */
        public function post(txt:*):void {
            var data:Object = new Object();

            data["txt"] = txt;
            data["id"] = new Date().time;

            netGroup.post(data);
        }

        /** Handle connection event listener */
        private function conHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
            if(e.info["code"] == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
                setupGroup();
            }
        }

        /** Connect to group */
        private function setupGroup():void {
            var groupSpec:GroupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier(groupName);

            groupSpec.postingEnabled = true;
            groupSpec.ipMulticastMemberUpdatesEnabled = true;
            groupSpec.addIPMulticastAddress("225.225.0.1:30000");

            netGroup = new NetGroup(netCon, groupSpec.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
            netGroup.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handler);

            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }
    }
}
```

Connection seems to be working, since I can send messages and the other player does receive them.. well.. receive something.

Then from my Main.as I call this class like this:

```
private var p2p:P2P;

public function Main():void {
    p2p = new P2P("snakybo", netHandler);
    p2p.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onConnected);
}

private function onConnected(e:Event):void {
    function send(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        c.post("a");
        trace("poseted");
    }

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, send);
}

private function netHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch(e.info["code"]) {
        case "NetGroup.Posting.Notify":
            trace("received: " + e.info["txt"]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, if I add:

```
case "NetGroup.Connection.Success":
    trace("Connected to group");
    break;
```

It never prints that. Not sure what's wrong with that.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Or did my PC somehow block Flash Player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your P2P class you have this...

```
netCon.connect("rtmfp:");
```

This tells your NetConnection to connect to a string ("rtmfp:") which isn't a server or valid connection type if you are trying to reach outside members of the rtmfp connection.  It appears you are using this for an internal network so "rtmfp" will work locally.

What I do with NetConnection.connect() is I set up my rtmfp constant and a developer key constant (for cirrus server) right off the bat like this...

```
cons SERVER:String = "rtmfp:";
cons DEVKEY:String = "your developer key here";
```

then

```
function connect(): void {
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatus);
    nc.connect(SERVER + DEVKEY);
}
```

You can go to adobes website if you are using their rtmfp server to get a developer key, they are free and easy to get anyway.  Once you are connected you will get a  NetStatus event string of "NetConnection.Connect.Success" which your conHandler function is set up to receive.  I use a Switch Case within mine to listen for the connect string and do something based off each string like this:

```
function netStatus(event: NetStatusEvent): void {
    switch (event.info.code) {
          case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
        setupGroup();
        break;
} }
```

Fire your setupGroup() function when you hear "NetConnection.Connect.Success".  Then within your setupGroup() go ahead and set your

```
groupspec.serverChannelEnabled = true; 
groupspec.routingEnabled = true;
groupspec.objectReplicationEnabled = true; // and I have     
groupspec.peerToPeerDisabled = false;
```

Also, in your setupGroup you are firing "handler" instead of "conHandler" which is the name of your NetStatus event function handler. Probably just a typo. Setting the new NetGroup itself will fire 1 of 3 NetStatus events telling you the status of the new netgroup connection so you won't need to dispatch the event you are using unless you want to, up to you.  You can handle those in your conHandler function as well.

I will typically have a trace statement setup to print out the NetStatusEvent so in your case that would be...  trace(e.info.code) and you will be able to see the events as they happen and be able to troubleshoot problems much easier.  Once you get this connection up you'll be able to handle the delivering of objects.

This should at least get you a created instance and the connection to others in the group.  I have included a couple links I referenced here:
    [NetGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetGroup.html)
    [NetStatus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html)
    [NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)

Try googling Tom Krcha, he is with adobe and has some good info on this as well.

Comment: thanks for the infos @E10 how about the "groupSpec.addIPMulticastAddress("225.225.0.1:30000");" do you still need all this?

Comment: just tested it and it works this is exactly what i was looking for..serverChannelEnabled etc. thanks allot!

Comment: You will only need to do that if you have a specific server to send data through or if you have a firewall filtering out UDP traffic.

Comment: thanks, i wasn't sure but i added all the suggestions - serverChannelEnabled, objectReplicationEnabled, peerToPeerDisabled and now its functioning had the "routingEnabled" already, will look into these parameters in more detail. cheers

Comment: do you know how to return all active groups when you set a name in the GroupSpecifier, i have checked through the AS3 properties for  NetGroup/GroupSpecifier etc but found nothing @E10 .

Comment: If our terms are consistent, I believe the number of active GROUPS would be the number of group specifiers you set up.  You can create new groups to handle separate instances of say, chat rooms.  You can have the client fire a unique key to the group upon a successful connection to the group or check out NetStatusEvent.  There are plenty of events in there that will help with knowing who is active to the session or not.  Hope that helps.